# Javascript scroll to element with animation onclick

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, onclick, onmousedown

I'm just starting out with JS and struggling. I got this lovely bit of code from Adam Khoury and it's working beautifully animated scrolling down the page to the target element.

The `ul` is within a fixed position navigation bar.

My question is: what code would be needed to make the animation scroll both up and down when the anchor in the `nav` is clicked?

```js
var scrollY = 0;
var distance = 10;
var speed = 24;

function autoScrollTo(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
  var bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
  var yPos = currentY + window.innerHeight;
  var animator = setTimeout('autoScrollTo(\'' + el + '\')', 24);
  if (yPos > bodyHeight) {
    clearTimeout(animator);
  } else {
    if (currentY < targetY - distance) {
      scrollY = currentY + distance;
      window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(animator);
    }
  }
}

function resetScroller(el) {
  var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
  var targetY = document.getElementById(el).offsetTop;
  var animator = setTimeout('resetScroller(\'' + el + '\')', speed);
  if (currentY > targetY) {
    scrollY = currentY - distance;
    window.scroll(0, scrollY);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(animator);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('about');">
      About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('testimonials');">
      Testimonials</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('contact');">
      Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr style="margin: 25em 0;" />

<div id="about" class="navButton">
  <p>About lorem ipsom....</p>
</div>

<div id="testimonials" class="navButton">
  <p>Testimonial lorem ipsom....</p>
</div>

<div id="contact" class="navButton">
  <p>Contact lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You got any live example of this?

Comment: In place of 'else {clearTimeout(animator);}', try 'else {scrollY = currentY-distance; window.scroll(currentY, scrollY);}'

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: Never use `setTimeout` with strings! It's like using evil `eval`. Use functions instead: `setTimeout(function(){autoScrollTo(el)}, 24)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dave for steering me away from javascript and on to JQuery. 
This bit of code is really newb friendly. You don't need to edit it at all, just paste it in your index.html and bam! and it works

```
<header class="main-header">

                <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
        </header>    

<!-- SMOOTH SCROLL -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
        </script>
        <!-- End of SMOOTH SCROLL -->
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use jQuery this will be much simpler. All you have to do is get the [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) top of the element you want to scroll to and then animate the [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) position using jQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```js
function autoScrollTo(el) {
    var top = $("#" + el).offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('about');">
      About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('testimonials');">
      Testimonials</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="autoScrollTo('contact');">
      Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr style="margin: 25em 0;" />

<div id="about" class="navButton">
  <p>About lorem ipsom....</p>
</div>

<div id="testimonials" class="navButton">
  <p>Testimonial lorem ipsom....</p>
</div>

<div id="contact" class="navButton">
  <p>Contact lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm up for anything that gets the same result with less effort/code. Sorry, i'm a total newb. You're saying I can replace all that js script with that one function? Do I need to include any certain links/files in my project to make the JQ work?

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is include jQuery, like I have in the script tag and replace your function with what I have written. The second parameter to the `.animate()` function is the total time the animation takes in milliseconds. The jQuery script is google-hosted so you don't even need to copy the library to your server.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction, Dave. Found a different script that's super short and sweet. Will post it.

Comment: Glad to help. If I successfully answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to put this all in a page to really test it out, but what I would try first is something along these lines:

```
    if(currentY < targetY-distance){
        scrollY = currentY+distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    } else {
        scrollY = currentY-distance;
        window.scroll(0, scrollY);
    }
```

So instead of clearing the timeout when currentY is greater than the targetY-distance, it scrolls in the opposite direction?  Might not work, but worth a shot...